# How to fire jQuery event on keyup [e.keyCode = 16 + e.keyCode = 37 or 38 or 39 or 40]?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me how can fire an jQuery event on keyup after check combination of two `keycodes {shiftkey + e.keyCode = 37 or 38 or 39 or 40}` ?

I wanna do some thing like below:
let we have an p tag with some text with class name editor
how

```
$(document).on('keyup','.editor p',function(e){
//here i want to check above query and fire event

})
```

Comment: Mouse events don't typically include keyboard event data. You probably want [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), then [`e.shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.shiftKey) and [`e.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Comment: yes sir u r right but when i set it as keyup.then in what way i can done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I missed to check it.  You can't do it using **`mouseup`** it should be a keypress or `keydown` or `keyup` event.

Thank you @JanDvorak for pointing it.

You can achieve it using [**`event.which`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) and binding with `keydown`

```
$(document).on('keydown','.editor p',function(e){
  if ((e.which === 37 && e.shiftKey) || (e.which === 38 && e.shiftKey) || 
     (e.which === 39 && e.shiftKey) || (e.which === 40 && e.shiftKey)) {

     //tODOs

   }
});
```

or also try this

```
if ( e.shiftKey && (e.which === 37 || e.which === 38 || 
                     e.which === 39 || e.which === 40) )
```

even simple like

This is called **Within condition** saying, keyCode within 37 to 40.

```
if ( e.shiftKey && (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40))
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Do the mouse events really hold the information about keyboard state?

Comment: @JanDvorak Sorry I did it wrong, edited to `keydown`.  Thank you for poining my mistake.

Comment: Thanks so much sir your code is much appreciated.both approaces u write above works fine for me please check i use it here http://jsfiddle.net/Karamjeetpnf/wsBKJ/5/ here 
again thanks a million

Comment: sir but third approach is not functionally works. can you plz examine the error in that.thanks in advance

Comment: @user2640758 Sorry its my mistake.  check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wsBKJ/10/.  This is called **WITHIN** condition.  IE., keycode within 37 to 40.  Hope you understand.

Comment: yes sir its working now .love the way you code.thanks to give me your valueable time.

Comment: @user2640758 I'm glad I was able to help. By the way, Sir is a very big word as I consider.  Better userID or call my name (I'm Praveen)

Comment: Please appreciate this for me it is correct word for you parveen sir i think you are from india i m also .actually i have just started programming career.help is much needed at this phase .SO nice of you.